# Change debian language to english

Tags: debian, language

How to change default interface language from french to english in all applications.

Everything in this terminal must be in english:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

1. Open a terminal
2. Become `root` — usually by running `sudo su` there
3. Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`
4. When presented with the list of locales, be sure to locate and check the setting reading "en_US.UTF-8" and/or "en_GB.UTF-8".

   The former uses "imperial" measures which might be strange for a French person, like "Letter" as the default paper size, while the latter is more sensible for an European ;-)
5. When asked about the default locale for the system, select one of those from the following step.

After the reconfiguration process finishes, reboot.

Oh, and be sure to read [the manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html#_the_locale) so that the checklist above does not appear to be some black voodoo.