# Change language debian 11 language from english to german

Tags: linux, debian, unix

I've tried changing my system language from english to german,without reinstalling the operational system. I've basically run the command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

as root.
I got an error as root:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

After selecting de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8, I got the following errors:

```
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8 LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
```

and when using the

```
locale
```

I got the following errors and messages

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note:
I've tried :
[Change debian language to english](https://superuser.com/questions/975138/change-debian-language-to-english)